# Hide subheader on scroll down, show on scroll up

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sub-header that must be static by default, hidden on scroll down and shown as a fixed on scroll up. There is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bagidolla/1qeocg4t/). I tried to mix an affix class of Bootstrap and this [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/), but it doesn't work.
My js code:

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('.header2').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}

$('#sticky').affix({
    offset: {
        top: 60
    }
});
```

Comment: *but it doesn't work*... can you elaborate? How specifically, does it not do what you need?

Comment: ok... Now when I scroll down and pass top header, the subheader becomes fixed, because of Bootstrap affix. But I want it to be static, just as top header. After I pass both headers, and scroll down onward, and again scroll back to top, only subheader must appear. Then when I come near to top, the subheader should be scrolled as a static.

Comment: Do you want header1 show first time only??

Comment: no, also when user reaches the top